Typing a dictionary entry object
I want to create a supertype to a bunch of key-value entry subtypes. The backend doesn't call the keys key and value, but somethingId and description:
{
  somethingId: 1,
  description: "Entity description"
}

The only thing that varies is something, according to each entity.
Is there a way to explain typescript to match such an object (viz., which have two props, description of type string and some other prop with type number)?
I tried:
type MyType = {
  [k: string]: number;
  description: string;
}

But this makes it think any keys, including description, should be numbers. If I put [k: string]: number | string, it will think the property could be either a number or a string, but I want it to understand the other property is a number.

You can use template literals for this:
type MyType = {
    [k: `${string}Id`]: number;
    description: string;
};

const example: MyType = {exampleId: 22, description: "hello"}

example.description // -> string
example.exampleId // -> number

The only problem is, that this approach cannot detect if certain key ending with Id is present. E.g. in this case it would show example.testId // -> number.

For my use case, it is perfect! Thnx!

You don’t need a mapped type and an intersection here. Just write { [k: \${string}Id`]: number; description: string}`. It’s an index signature.

@jcalz good catch! I was misremembering that [k: ...] is supposed to be [k in ...] and then logically got error due to using mapped type and description together - which is why I went for intersection.

So then do you want to edit this and specifically link to the docs for pattern template literal index signatures?
